# Is there an escaping character (when using double-quotes in string declarations)?

Tags: autoit

This is the code I'm running:

```
RunWait("ComSpec & " /c Start 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe'")
```

I have also tried without semiquotes and with quotes but then I get syntax errors.

Comment: What is a "semiquote"?

Comment: You definitely have a quote mismatch. There's 3 double quotes and 2 single quotes. It's not clear what string you meant to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the file path on your computer has spaces in it and needs double-quotations around it.

Try "D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe" from the command prompt with the double-quotations and make sure the program starts.

Once you know it works you can add it to your AutoIt code like so (notice that it is surrounded by single-quotations).

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe"')
```

Answer (score 3):

In AutoIt, you can escape quotes simply by repeating them (same way it happens on Batch/DOS):

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c ""Start D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe""")
```

Comment: Yes, this is probably the real answer. But can you add a reference (e.g. to documentation) to back up the claim?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a problem with the amount of quotes in your code. I would do something like this:

```
(RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c Start" & "D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe")
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an unmatched `"` in the middle.

Usually / or \ are used for escaping. Try /" or \" because I'm not sure which of both works with AutoIt.

Comment: They both don't work in AutoIt. The only way seems to be string concatenation using different string characters (`'` and `"`)

Comment: It's possible to escape by double-typing it (i.e. `MsgBox(0, "Test", "Hello, ""world""")` will output Hello, "world"

Answer (score -1):

As per [Documentation - FAQ - Double quotes](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/faq.htm#3):

> If you want to use double-quotes inside a string then you must "double them up". So for every one quote you want you should use two. ...
>
> or use single quotes instead ...

Examples:

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & """D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe""")
RunWait(@ComSpec & ' /c ' & '"D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe"')
```

However, there is no need for the "SPECified secondary COMmand interpreter" (or `@ComSpec`), nor escaping of double-quotes. Example:

```
Global Const $g_sFile = "D:\Program Files (x86)\Pidgin\pidgin.exe"

Run($g_sFile, "")
```

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).